# Covariance of OLS estimator and residual = 0. Where is the mistake?

Tags: linear-model, least-squares

$Cov(b,e|X)$, where $b$ is the OLS estimator of the coefficients, $e$ is the residual vector, and $X$ is the regressor matrix.

We know that $Cov(b,e|X)=E(be'|X)-E(b|X)E(e'|X)$ where ' $'$ ' is the transpose operator.

$E(be'|X)=E((X'X)^{-1}X'Y\epsilon'M')$, where $M$ is the annihilator matrix, $\epsilon$ the error vector, and $Y$ the dependent vector.

$E((X'X)^{-1}X'(X\beta+\epsilon)\epsilon'M|X)=E(\beta+(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon\epsilon'M)\\=\beta+(X'X)^{-1}X'E(\epsilon\epsilon')M=\beta+(X'X)^{-1}X'\sigma^2I_nM=\beta$

For the second term:
$E(e|X)=E(M\epsilon|X)=0$, by strict exogeneity.

So, I get $Cov(b,e|X)=\beta$, which is wrong... So, where is my mistake?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to post-multiply the first term by $\epsilon'M$.

$$E((X'X)^{-1}X'(X\beta+\epsilon)\epsilon'M\mid X)$$

$$=(X'X)^{-1}X'X\beta E(\epsilon'\mid X)M +(X'X)^{-1}X'E(\epsilon\epsilon'\mid X)M$$

$$= \beta \cdot 0 \cdot M + \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}(MX)' = 0+0=0$$